# Powershell include variable in output csv

Tags: csv, powershell

How can I easily add the input country to each line in the output csv file so that if I execute this with several countries for the country parameter I get the country info on each line?

```
param([string[]]$Country="Norway",[string]$file="ExUsersNO.csv")

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
foreach ($i in $Country)
{
    Get-ADUser -searchbase "ou=$i,ou=FMS,dc=xx,dc=xx,dc=com" -Filter * -properties msExchVersion,name,mail,DistinguishedName,whenCreated |
    Select-Object -Property name,mail,DistinguishedName,msExchVersion,whenCreated |
    Sort-Object name |
    Export-Csv -Path ".\$file" -Append -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) with your `select` statement:

```
select name,mail,DistinguishedName,msExchVersion,whenCreated,@{Name='Country';Expression={$i}}
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked like a charm! (But I had to change the "," to ";"  from ...'Country',Expression... to ...'Country';Expression...

Comment: Sorry about that, typo on my part. If it solved your problem, please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left